# Why is Convergence in Distribution defined in weak terms?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, definition, weak-convergence

**Why is convergence in distribution defined in terms of "weak" convergence in the law?**

Intuitively, (at least at a literal level) convergence in distribution of $(X_n)_n$ sequence of Borel random variables should imply "convergence" in the **Law** of these random variables. If I were to **guess** the definition of Convergence in Distribution before studying it, I would probably say:

> $X_n \stackrel{d}{\to} X$ if $\mu_{X_n}(S) \to \mu_X(S)$ for all Borel $S$.

This is obviously a lot stronger than the actual definition of Convergence in Distribution. **But what would be the problem if we defined it this way?**

**Here is the definition of Convergence in Distribution introduced in my Probability class:**

*Definition of Convergence in Distribution:*

> Fix $(X_m)_{m = 1} ^\infty$ of random vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$(they may live on different probability spaces) and $X$ random vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then $X_n \stackrel{d}{\to} X$ in distribution if $\mu_{X_n} \stackrel{w}{\to} \mu_X$.

*Definition of Weak Convergence in probability:*

> $\mu_{X_n} \stackrel{w}{\to} \mu_X$ means $\int_\mathbb{R^n} h \,d\mu_{X_n} \to \int_\mathbb{R^n} h \,d\mu_X$ for all $h: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous and bounded.

Comment: your first intuitive definition is equivalent to the definition of weak convergence you give below if you replace "all Borel $S$" with "all continuity sets $S$ of $\mu_X$" by the Portmanteau theorem

Comment: @G.Gare Yes. This is again a lot weaker than what I intuitively thought convergence in distribution is.

Comment: For example, CLT would stop working for non-continuous variables.

Comment: Take a normal distribution with variance $\epsilon$. As $\epsilon\to 0$ it is intuitively clear that this should converge in distribution to the $0$ random variable. Now take your borel set $B$ to be $\{0\}$ and you see that the convergence would fail under your definition.